# Help to evaluate $\int\ t^2 \sin\beta t\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int\ t^2 \sin\beta t\, dt$

How do I treat
$\sin\beta t$ 
?

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts twice, while acting the differentiation on $t^2$ till it becomes a constant. You can integrate the $\sin(\beta t)$ part through a change in variable $y=\beta t$ and the rule for integrating $\sin(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is for integration by parts $\int u dv=uv -\int v du$ applied 2 times: First, let $u=t^2$ and $dv=\sin \beta t dt$; then $du=2t dt$ and $v=-\frac{1}{\beta}\cos \beta t$, so
$$\int t^2\sin \beta t \,dt = -\frac{1}{\beta}t^2\cos \beta t+\int \frac{1}{\beta}\cos \beta t\, 2t dt=-\frac{t^2}{\beta}\cos \beta t+\frac{2}{\beta}\int t\cos \beta t\, dt.$$
Now, let $u=t$ and $dv=\cos \beta t\, dt$. Then we find $du=dt$ and $v=\frac{1}{\beta}\sin \beta t$ and so
$$\int t^2\sin \beta t \,dt =-\frac{t^2}{\beta}\cos \beta t+\frac{2}{\beta}\left[\frac{t}{\beta}\sin \beta t-\int \frac{1}{\beta}\sin \beta t\, dt \right] =$$
$$=-\frac{t^2}{\beta}\cos \beta t+\frac{2t}{\beta^2}\sin \beta t -\frac{2}{\beta^2}\int \sin \beta t \, dt=$$
$$=-\frac{t^2}{\beta}\cos \beta t+\frac{2t}{\beta^2}\sin \beta t -\frac{2}{\beta^2}\left( -\frac{1}{\beta}\cos \beta t +c\right) =$$
$$=-\frac{t^2}{\beta}\cos \beta t+\frac{2t}{\beta^2}\sin \beta t +\frac{2}{\beta^3} \cos \beta t +c. $$

Answer (score 1):

You could use integration by parts and treat $\sin(\beta t)$ as your $dv$. That is, $dv$ in the following:

$$\int u\ dv = uv-\int v\ du$$